# Отображение элементов при помощи List

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему в данном случае список отображаемых элементов HealthIcon[i] будет равен Health, а не величине листа. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
maxHealth имеет постоянную велечину 8.

```
public GameObject HealthIconPrefab;
public List<GameObject> HealthIcon = new List<GameObject>();
public void Setup(int maxHealth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxHealth; i++)
    {
        GameObject newIcon = Instantiate(HealthIconPrefab, transform);
        HealthIcon.Add(newIcon);
    }
}

public void DisplayHealth(int Health)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HealthIcon.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < Health)
        {
            HealthIcon[i].SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            HealthIcon[i].SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: слово "листья" или `leafs` я в коде не вижу, по-этому не очень понимаю вопрос. Почему `HealthIcon[i]` это объекты Helth - потому что в цикле, внутри метод `Setup` список заполняется объектами, созданными из префаба `HealthIconPrefab`

Comment: List - подразумевает под собой public List<GameObject> HealthIcon = new List<GameObject>();
Дело в том что метод DisplayHealth. Работает в таком формате:
Мы передаем Health. Условно 5. 
Он проверяет i(8 ) < 5.
Если да, то активируем объекты согласно списку HealthIcon[i].SetActive(true).
Почему HealthIcon[i] при использовании логики равен 8, а активируется количество объектов равное Health.

Comment: _активируется количество объектов равное Health_ - ну так вы же сами проверяете условие `if (i < Health)`. Что написали, так и работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собака порылась в этой тонкости: "список отображаемых элементов HealthIcon[i] будет равен Health, а не величине листа". Из продемострированного кода не видно, как будет отображаться список HealthIcon, а видно только, что его первые элементы в заданном количестве активируются в DisplayHealth. Не знаю, как устроено Unity3D, но оно может отображать только активированные элементы. По идее, оно должно отображать все элементы из списка, но в разном виде в зависимости от состояния. Возможно, что состояние активации это не тот признак, по которому элементы отображаются различным способом.